# Spring JPA With mongo Supporting Contains and LessThan

Tags: spring, mongodb, spring-boot, spring-mongodb

I am using Spring JPA with mongo.I have a requirement to use contains query on one of the fields.If end users(UI/Service) hits the GET Request and looks for information in EMAIL Field,I need to search based on text.Pretty much it is **like**.
https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/

This link explains that We can Use Contains to get the Data.

```
List<ScheduledNotification> findByMobileNumberContaining(String mobileNumber);
    List<ScheduledNotification> findByEmailIdIgnoreCaseContaining(String emailId);
```

But when I am using this API,I am not able to get the data.So ,has any one done something like using Contains.

Comment: … where x.MobileNumber like ?1 (parameter bound wrapped in %)
Are you using "%" with your mobile no?

Comment: Afridi I am not using any % with input.My controller just grabs it from Request and sends it to Service method,which in turn gets data from methods mentioned above

Comment: @NeilStockton I did not get your point

Comment: public interface ScheduledNotificationRepository extends BaseRepository<com.innoviti.notification.model.ScheduledNotification, String>,ScheduledNotificationRepositoryCustom {

 List<ScheduledNotification>findByNotificationMediumSMSAllIgnoreCase(String notificationMediumSMS);
 List<ScheduledNotification>findByNotificationMediumEmailAllIgnoreCase(String notificationMediumEmail);
 List<ScheduledNotification> findByMobileNumberContaining(String mobileNumber);
 List<ScheduledNotification> findByEmailIdIgnoreCaseContaining(String emailId);

}

Comment: You are using Spring-MongoDB, not Spring-Data-JPA. Anybody using a technology ought to know what is being used

Comment: According to spring document, your input parameter should be wrapped in  between "%".  Its been mentioned in spring documentation: "… where x.firstname like ?1 (parameter bound wrapped in %)"

Comment: @Afridi Yes i went through that.But Spring Mongo provides the implementation for Contains data.All I have to do it formulate the method and done.Again as said,error message I was getting did not have anything to do with spring mongo thing.

Comment: @NeilStockton Ok after reading docs,I got the point you are trying to make

Answer (score 0):

well ,I was not sending content type in header attribute in GET request.So yes it works,alright.There was no issue with method signature.